# How to use Rowbounds class in Mybatis mapper.xml?

Tags: spring, pagination, mybatis

I'm trying to implement board paging feature. However I don't know how to use 
Rowbounds in mapper file.

For example:

DAO

```
public List<BoardVO> getList(DataVO vo) {
    int offset=1;
    int limit=15;
    RowBounds rowbound = new RowBounds(offset, limit);

    return session.selectList("board.getBoardList", requestStation,rowbound);
}
```

I made that and then:

mapper.xml

```
[select id="getList" parameterType="com.java.test.DataVO" 
resultType="com.java.test.DataVO"] 

SELECT * FROM board
order by seq desc limit #{offset},#{limit}
```

but that is not working.

Error message:

> ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'offset' in
>   'class com.java.test.DataVO'

Comment: code formatting

Comment: Can we have your DataVO class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the limit suffix.
like this:

```
SELECT * FROM board order by seq desc
```